# Building my Xamarin.Forms app is not producing an Android bundle .aab file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, latest update.  I have updated NuGet to the latest Xamarin.Forms (5.0.0).  Under Android Options / Android Package Format, I have chosen 'bundle'.

In Debug, I'm able to deploy .apk successfully to my phone for testing.  I see the .apk file under MyProject.Android\bin\Debug

In Release, when I build, the build is successful, but all I get under bin\Release are .dll and .pdb files, but I don't get an Android bundle (.aab) file.  Nor a .apk file.

What more do I have to do to get a .aab file when I build??

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wasn't getting a .aab file was that it is only created when you RUN the solution.  It will then deploy to the emulator or your device, and for that, it has to create the .aab file, and that's when you have it.